# How to instruct CuPy to run multiple number of the same job concurrently in a GPU?

Tags: python, concurrency, gpgpu, cupy

Below is a simple function called `job()` that performs several CuPy tasks in the GPU.

How do I instruct CuPy to run `job()` a million times concurrently and thereafter aggregate their results?

The intent of my question is to understand how to submit multiple concurrent jobs to one GPU via CuPy.

**Test Script**

```
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

def job( nsamples ):
    # Do some CuPy tasks in GPU
    d_a = cp.random.randn( nsamples )
    d_b = cp.random.randint( -3, high=3, size=nsamples )
    d_result = ( d_a + d_b )
    d_hist, _ = cp.histogram( d_result, bins=cp.array([-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4]) )
    std = cp.std( d_hist )
    return std

# Perform 1 job in GPU
nsamples = 10 #can be as large as tens to hundreds of thousands
std = job( nsamples, 0 )
print( 'std', std, type(std) )
```

**Update:**

```
# Create Cuda streams
d_streams = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    d_streams.append( cp.cuda.stream.Stream( non_blocking=True ) )

# Perform Concurrent jobs via Cuda Stream.
results = []
for stream in d_streams:
    with stream:
        results.append( job( nsamples ) )
print( 'results', results, len(results), type(std) )
```

After reading this [Nvidia developer blog on Cuda Stream](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency/), this CuPy issue on [Support CUDA stream with stream memory pool](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/pull/306) and this SOF question on [CuPy Concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59263904/cupy-concurrency), I have tried the above which seems to work. However, I don't know how to see whether the jobs are running concurrently or serially.

Questions:

1. How do I profile Cupy's execution of the jobs in the GPU to evaluate my script is doing what I want? Ans: `nvprof --print-gpu-trace python filename.py`
2. Is there a limit on the number streams that I can issue (e.g. limited by some hardware) or is it "infinite"?

Comment: you're thinking task parallel.  You want to think data parallel.

Comment: @RobertCrovella can you elaborate or refer me to documentation on what you mean. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation in general would be to concatenate all your data together (across jobs) and seek to complete the work in a data parallel way.  Here's a rough example:

```
$ cat t34.py
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

def job( nsamples, njobs ):
    # Do some CuPy tasks in GPU
    d_a = cp.random.randn( nsamples, njobs )
    d_b = cp.random.randint( -3, high=3, size=(nsamples, njobs) )
    d_result = ( d_a + d_b )
    mybins = cp.array([-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4])
    d_hist = cp.zeros((njobs,mybins.shape[0]-1))
    for i in range(njobs):
      d_hist[i,:], _ = cp.histogram( d_result[i,:], bins=mybins )
    std = cp.std( d_hist, axis=1 )
    return std

nsamples = 10 #can be as large as tens to hundreds of thousands
std = job( nsamples, 2 )
print( 'std', std, type(std) )
$ python t34.py
std [0.69985421 0.45175395] <class 'cupy.core.core.ndarray'>
$
```

For most of the operations in `job` we can perform the appropriate `cupy` operation to take care of the work for all the jobs.  To pick one example, the `std` function can readily extend to perform its work across all jobs.  `histogram` is the exception, as that routine in numpy or cupy does not allow for a partitioned/segmented algorithm, that I can see.  So I have used a loop for that.   If this were the actual work you wanted to do, it might be possible to write a partitioned histogram cupy routine as a [cupy kernel](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/tutorial/kernel.html).  Another alternative would be to issue just the cupy histogram in streams.

Comment: Wow! This is awesome. So simply adding another axis or dimension to represent 'njobs` in each `ndarray` object, I can compactly express what I need to do and better leverage the power of the `ndarray` object. I need time to digest the 2nd part of your explanation on the histogram. Is there a limit to the size of each axis? How do determine that? I do need to get a histogram on one of the axis of the results. Can you point me to an example(s) on how to write a partitioned-histogram-cupy-routine as a cupy kernel or issue the cupy histogram in streams? I would like to learn that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of general limits on axis sizes.  I would generally start with the memory on your GPU as defining the upper bound of the array(s).  I don't know of a tutorial on writing a cupy kernel histogram routine.  I would try to learn these things: 1. How to write a histogram in CUDA, such as [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-fast-histograms-using-shared-atomics-maxwell/)  2. How to write a segmented algorithm in CUDA 3. How to write a [cupy kernel](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/tutorial/kernel.html) and then combine all that knowledge.